# Data truncation: Data too long for column grails GSP field

Tags: grails, gsp

I have this domain class in my project.
This is a sample

```
public class empHistory {

String respField
String addInfo

static constraints = {

        respField(nullable: true, maxSize:100)
        updatedByUser(nullable: true, maxSize:100)
    }
```

after providing the field value for both fields when i click ok its displaying the following error

```
Data truncation: Data too long for column 'respField' in row 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may have entered more than the specified max value.
so if you need to expand the size for example you can do like this

```
public class empHistory {

String respField
String addInfo

static constraints = {

        respField(nullable: true, maxSize:2000)
        updatedByUser(nullable: true, maxSize:2000)
    }
```

If `dbcreate` status is update change it to `create` or `create-drop` then try to run your application again. it's because the database is already created in the first constraint.

Comment: @user3679427 what is the `dbcreate` status in the development environment. see in `DataSOurce.groovy` file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your column type in the database.

`L` is the lenght of the data to be stored.

```
TINYBLOB, TINYTEXT :        L + 1 bytes, where L < 28
BLOB, TEXT :                L + 2 bytes, where L < 216
MEDIUMBLOB, MEDIUMTEXT :    L + 3 bytes, where L < 224
LONGBLOB, LONGTEXT :        L + 4 bytes, where L < 232
```

For example, if you want to upload large pictures or files. You should change the default `TINYBLOB` data type to `LONGBLOB`

If you are using MySQL, you can find more info here: [Data Type Storage Requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html).